# How to style input box(use codemirror) of ThebeLab?

Tags: editor, codemirror

I am trying to integrate the [ThebeLab javascript library](https://thebelab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) with my web application. Now so far, using their example code, I am able to integrate successfully. ThebeLab uses a Codemirror editor for its input field. And as per [ThebeLab's official documentation](https://thebelab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/cm_customize.html), we can even customize the Codemirror editor using the configuration settings provided by Codemirror itself.

Now, when I am trying to customize the Codemirror editor using the [example](https://thebelab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/cm_customize.html) provided by ThebeLab, it is not working. It doesn't even throw any kind of error in console either. Even, the example provided by the ThebeLab on their official web page is itself doesn't work.

[image]

Now, this issue is already raised and closed on their official [GitHub repository](https://github.com/minrk/thebelab/issues/126). And as per them, the solution is already provided with the newer version(0.5.1) of ThebeLab javascript. And I am also using the newer version which is 0.5.1, but still, it is not working.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Thebe Lab examples</title>

        <!-- Configure and load Thebe !-->
        <script type="text/x-thebe-config">
        {
            bootstrap: true,
            requestKernel: true,
            kernelOptions: {
                name: "python3",
                serverSettings: {
                    "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
                    "token": "test-secret"
                }
            },
            codeMirrorConfig: {
                theme: "abcdef"
            },
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/thebelab@latest" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Thebe Lab: using a local server</h1>

        <p>This page illustrates how to setup Thebe Lab, using a local Jupyter server as kernel provider. This assumes that you have started the local server as:
            <pre>
                jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=test-secret --NotebookApp.allow_origin='<span id="origin">*</span>'
            </pre>
        and that it's running on port 8888
        </p>

        <pre data-executable="true" data-language="python">print("Hello!")</pre>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('origin').innerHTML = location.origin;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me out here soon. Thank you.

Comment: I've also had issues with this. I opened another ticket today addressing this issue since I'm experiencing the same. My fix was to override styling using CSS & jQuery, which isn't ideal, but works.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for letting me know.